# Changing a loop variable within the loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am building a small script to perform a task.  I am using a `for` loop in a section of my code to give me a list, however, I need the list to not be in perfect order as its being generated. To do this I attempted to reverse the string variable “chat” within the loop in the hopes of affecting the value of the loop variable.

However, my code doesn’t seem to be doing that since I get a clean `aaa`, `aab`, etc. output when it runs, regardless if I comment out the line `char = char[::-1]` or not.

Is what I am trying to do possible with for loop? Or is there any other way to this? And how can I get a more random order in my result in another way?

Also, I am using the list to make sure I don't get duplicates and I am printing char at the end to make sure it’s changed except it doesn’t seem to be going through the loop.

Here is the code.

```
import time 
import itertools

char = "abc"
counter = 0
x = []
for i in itertools.product(char, repeat=3):
    if ''.join(i)in x:
        break

    print(''.join(i))
    counter += 1
    char = char[::-1]
    x.append(''.join(i))

print('[+] Printed ' + str(counter)+ ' charecters.')

print(char)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is an example of your expected output?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking for, but I can address one point: When you pass `char` to `itertools.product`, the current object referenced by `char` is cached inside `itertools.product`. Rebinding `char` to point to a new object (e.g. `char[::-1]`) does not change the value `itertools.product` is using, it will always be based on the original value bound to `char`, `"abc"`, not the later `"cba"`.

Comment: If your output is not too massive, you could maybe store it in a list, shuffle it, then pop from it?

Comment: @will.mrt7 Could you briefly explain what it is that you understand `itertools.product` to be doing? I get the feeling it doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking about, but let me try to solve the problem you have :)

```
import itertools
from random import shuffle

char = "abc"

items = [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(char, repeat=len(char))]
shuffle(items)

print('\n'.join(items))
print('[+] Printed {} charecters.'.format(len(items)))
```

```
python test123.py
bbb
aca
bcb
abb
aab
bcc
acb
cca
abc
ccc
cac
caa
ccb
bca
cbb
bba
aba
aac
baa
bab
bac
cbc
bbc
acc
aaa
cab
cba
[+] Printed 27 charecters.
```

> every run it generates the same "products list" but in a different order

### Superfast "product" list generator with randomized output under the hood!

I've spent some time and got the working example

```
import itertools
from contextlib import contextmanager
from random import shuffle, sample
from datetime import datetime

char = "abcdefgf"


def generate_product(char):
    items = []
    for i, item in enumerate(itertools.product(char, repeat=len(char))):
        items.append("".join(item))
    shuffle(items)

    return items


def generate(char):
    pools = (char,) * len(char)

    result = ['']
    for i, pool in enumerate(pools):
        # let's shuffle the pool, it will randomize output without extra performance hit
        pool_rnd = sample(pool, k=len(pool))

        result = [x + y for x in result for y in pool_rnd]

    return result


@contextmanager
def timeit(name):
    start = datetime.now()
    print('Started "{}" at {}. Please wait ...'.format(name, start))

    yield

    end = datetime.now()
    print('Finished "{}" at {}! Execution took {}'.format(name, start, end - start))


with timeit('generate_product'):
    items1 = generate_product(char)
    # # print('\n'.join(items1))
    print(' > Contains {} charecters.'.format(len(items1)))

with timeit('generate'):
    items2 = generate(char)
    # print('\n'.join(items2))
    print(' > Contains {} charecters.'.format(len(items2)))

print('Are equal? Sorted comparision result={}'.format(sorted(items1) == sorted(items2)))
```

Compare the speed!

```
#> python test123.py

Started "generate_product" at 2019-12-13 05:35:39.219348. Please wait ...
 > Contains 16777216 charecters.
Finished "generate_product" at 2019-12-13 05:35:39.219348! Execution took 0:00:30.075320
Started "generate" at 2019-12-13 05:36:09.294871. Please wait ...
 > Contains 16777216 charecters.
Finished "generate" at 2019-12-13 05:36:09.294871! Execution took 0:00:02.998755
Are equal? Sorted comparision result=True
```

Just `0:00:02.998755` against `0:00:30.075320`! That's a victory I believe!

One more "stress-test" for the algorithm!

> Started "generate" at 2019-12-13 05:39:01.434788. Please wait ...
>   Contains 387420489 charecters.
>   Finished "generate" at 2019-12-13 05:39:01.434788! Execution took 0:01:20.306413

80 seconds to generate list of 387_420_489 combinations! I consumed 25 GB or RAM :D

Comment: Thanks, that’s exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Actually looking at it closely, what I am trying to do is the same thing,  but producing the output as ittertools creates it.  In other words I am trying to save as much time as posible so I don’t want to create a list and then iterate over it.

Comment: @will.mrt7 itertools doesn't produce anything. It returns a generator function which generates values when you overate over it. So we are safe here and iterate over it only once (actually twice, because `random.shuffle` iterates as well). Do you need a very high performance solution? I know how it could be done in one iteration if you really need it :) https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Comment: Yes I do, to give you and idea of what i am trying to do.  I want to create a program that creates a word list for brut forcing passwords(for ethical purpose of course). In my idea the word list is generated from top to button. So that It finds the missing item faster, it gives it 2 out of 3 chances greater than something like crunch for example.  I have already build a program using muiltiprocess and threating and running two for loops at the same time, it beats a regular word list generater, but I am losing speed as the charecters get higher.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: aaah, so in this case. have you tried my solution? Because I see a potential performance problem in your source code block where you check that generated string already in `x`. Lists are ugly for `in` operator. They use `for ...` internally for every `in` call.

Comment: @will.mrt7 take a look at the edit I've made just. That's super-crazy super-fast now! Blazing!!!

Comment: I believe my answer should be approved =) ok, I have to go to bed

Comment: Yeah for sure!  I’ll check it when I get home.  That looks really fast.

Answer (score -2):

You are changing `char` inside the loop, which is iterating over `product(char, repeat=3)`.

Although `char` is changed every time (you can check this by printing it), it does not affect the data you're looping over. That makes sense if you think about it: what would you expect would happen exactly?

The loop simply completes iterating over the original product and every value will show up in order, reversing `char` does nothing.

If you were trying to show all three character combinations of characters from the original string, but in a random order, this would work:

```
import random
import itertools

chars = 'abc'

result = list(itertools.product(chars, repeat=3))
random.shuffle(result)

for x in result:
    print(''.join(x))
```